HTML to image html2image doesn't save files
My main goal is to save pandas dataframe with html and scc styles as image. I'm having problems imgkit so I tried html2image. And it worked for me. But a few days later the same code doesn't do anything. No error either. I even created a new venv with html2imageonly and ran simple code from other examples
from html2image import Html2Image
hti = Html2Image()

html = '<h1> A title </h1> Some text.'
css = 'body {background: red;}'

# screenshot an HTML string (css is optional)
hti.screenshot(html_str=html, css_str=css, save_as='page.png')

However, it doesn't save anything, and just finishes programm with "Process finished with exit code 0".
I also tried looking in Temp\html2image and only found file from when the pachage was working.
Tried downgrading to 2.0.4, still no results.
First version of code looked like this
    html = s.set_td_classes(cell_color).to_html()
    root = get_project_root()
    image_path = pathlib.Path(root, 'resources')
    hti = Html2Image(output_path=image_path)
    image_name = 'top_5_table.png'
    hti.screenshot(html_str=html, css_str=CSS, save_as=image_name)

And it stopped working. I've tried removing css_str, changing output_path, still no result
I'm trying all of the versions, 1.1.3 and 2.0.3 at least save html files, not png, and to Temp\html2image

There has recently been updates to Chromium which are causing this problem.  As of today (September 7th, 2024) the issue appears to affect both Chrome and Edge browser based on Chromium version 128.0.x.x and higher.  There is no resolution at this point other than downgrading the browser version or embedding Chromium or a portable version of Chrome directly into your app.  This GitHub issue has been created to track the problem.
Update (September 9th 2024):
Version 2.0.5 of html2image has been released and it addresses the problem identified by the OP.

The Chrome Driver may need to be properly configured.

Based on this document, install the Chrome Driver that matches your environment.

Mac users with Homebrew installed: brew install --cask chromedriver
Debian based Linux distros: sudo apt-get install chromium-driver
Windows users with Chocolatey installed: choco install chromedriver


Also based on the document, get the Chrome Driver executable_path according to your operating system.

Linux: /usr/bin/google-chrome
Mac:   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
Windows: Vista and newer:  C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

However, it's might be a little different in practical situation. Dig into the similar folder and find the actual chromedriver.
In my case, it's named as /usr/bin/chromedriver.

Enter the executable_path path found above or specify the browser type.
from html2image import Html2Image
hti = Html2Image(
    browser_executable=<executable-path-found-above>, 
    custom_flags=[
        '--no-sandbox', 
        '--headless', 
        '--disable-gpu', 
        '--disable-software-rasterizer', 
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ])

# OR

hti = Html2Image(
    browser="chrome", 
    custom_flags=[
        '--no-sandbox', 
        '--headless', 
        '--disable-gpu', 
        '--disable-software-rasterizer', 
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ])

html = "<h1> An interesting title </h1> This page will be red"
css = """body {background: red;}"""

hti.screenshot(html_str=html, css_str=css, save_as='red_page.png')



